# Data not retrieving in view passed from controller. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm having problem retrieving data from controller to view passed from redirect. I have used following code:
Controller:

```
return Redirect::to('Seller/register')

            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->with($oldinput);

    }
```

View:

```
<input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="" required="" value=" {!!  $oldinput->fname !!}" >
```

I'm getting error as: `Undefined variable: oldinput (View: C:\Users\Man'ish\Automobile\resources\views\Sellers\register.blade.php)`
Can anyone tell me what's wrong in here?

Comment: $oldinput is not created anywhere

Comment: I created on controller as $oldinput=$request->all();. 
How do i retrieve this? do i have to make object in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set the variable, you are only sending the value:

```
return Redirect::to('Seller/register')

        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->with('oldinput', $oldinput);

}
```

When redirecting, you have to remember you have to use Session to get the value in your blade view:

```
{!! session('oldvalue')->fname !!}
```

Take a look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data